# Apply Google Tag Manager on Just One Page on a Website

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

In Google Tag Manager's user guide, it is instructed to add the GTM snippets to every page on the site.  What would happen if we just place this on just selected pages and not every page?  I just want to track one page and not all pages.  I'm new to GTM and that's why I am a bit confused.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely do that. There are some considerations / consequences to this approach and why it isn't recommended. Essentially reports via google analytics UI will have inaccurate or meaningless data.

1. path reports where you can track where users go on the site won't contain any data
2. time based reports where you can see how long someone was on your site and what they did will be inaccurate.

You might want to consider having the container on every page and a page view tag to get that information.
If you want to tag a specific behaviour you can create a different tag which only fires on a given condition. i.e a conversion.

Hope that helps.

Comment: We have got a dataLayer on one oft he pages that will collect analytics for our sales.  Do you think that would also be affected?  It is where the order is finalized and the product information is passed in to the dataLayer for analysis.

Comment: If I understand correctly the one page that has dataLayer is the one page that is being tracked with google analytics via google tag manager? If this is the case then no it shouldn't be affected. The standard tracking pixel on every other page will collect general info / data (same for every site that uses google analytics) this data is in standard reports. On the sales page there is additional data which probably makes sense in terms of conversion. i.e the car was red or blue etc. Shouldn't interfere. Bare in mind that there are session and user based data and you can populate in dataLayer.